# Assign single element to an IntArray value attribute in Kotlin annotations

Tags: annotations, kotlin

I have a custom annotation declared as

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Anno(val value: IntArray, val attr2: Int = 0)
```

For a single element declaration, I'm able to use the above annotation in a Java class as

```
@Anno(1)
```

but while writing the same in a Kotlin class, I have to put enclosing brackets

```
@Anno([1])
```

Aren't the brackets unnecessary in this case or am I declaring the annotation wrong? I am using Kotlin version 1.2.0-rc-39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, square brackets (Kotlin 1.2+) or `arrayOf` (Kotlin 1.2-) are required.

But as long as this is your annotation, written in Kotlin, you can do [fancy things](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html) with it, like taking lambdas or varargs, so you can try to tune the resulting syntax for your need. For example, this will be valid syntax, even in Kotlin 1.2-:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Anno(
    val attribute: String,
    vararg val value: Int
)

@Anno("test", 1, 2, 3)
fun test() = 42
```

You'll need to put `vararg` parameter at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the vararg modifier. This works as expected